# unable to submit form having multi select in spring mvc application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Using spring mvc, I am working on a page which allows users to select multiple skills (using multi-select). I am able to display skills.But when I select skills and click on submit, I am seeing below error.

```
org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'candidate' on field 'skills': rejected value [1,3,4]; codes [typeMismatch.candidate.skills,typeMismatch.skills,typeMismatch.java.util.List,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [candidate.skills,skills]; arguments []; default message [skills]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String[]' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'skills'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.cts.form.SkillForm] for property 'skills[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
```

Below is my code :

```
public class CandidateForm {

private String name;
..........
private List<SkillForm> skills;
.. setters ad getters
```

}

```
public class SkillForm {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String isSelected;
  ......... setters and getters
}
```

--- jsp

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <form:label for="skills" path="skills">Candidate Primary Skills *</form:label>
                            <form:select multiple="true" path="skills" class="form-control input-sm" id="skills" >
                                <c:forEach var="item" items="${candidate.skills}">
                                    <form:option selected="${item.isSelected}" value="${item.id}" >${item.name}</form:option>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </form:select>
                        </div>
```

---

formatter

```
@Component
public class SkillFormatter implements Formatter<SkillForm>{

    public SkillFormatter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public String print(SkillForm object, Locale locale) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return object.getId().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public SkillForm parse(String text, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SkillForm form = new SkillForm();
        form.setId(Integer.parseInt(text));
        return form;
    }
```

---

bean configuration

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.cts.formatter" />
    <beans:bean id="conversionService"
        class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="formatters">
            <beans:set>
                <beans:ref bean="skillFormatter" />
            </beans:set>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" />
```

---

controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/candidate/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
        public String submitNewCandidate(@ModelAttribute("candidate") CandidateForm form, ModelMap model,BindingResult bindingResult) {
            if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
                logger.debug("createCandidate is executed!");
            }
            -----------------------
            return "newCandidate";
        }
```

---

I have this [page](http://springinpractice.com/2012/01/07/making-formselect-work-nicely-using-spring-3-formatters) as reference . CAn you anybody give some inputs as to why, even though I have configured formatter, it is not invoked ? Should I do anything in the controller method ?.. Is there any better implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

I copy your code to my springmvc project ,but it's successful.I paste my code following.

```
<bean id="skillFormatter" class="org.spring.test.test.SkillFormatter"></bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService"/>
```

are you sure that your formatter is registered correctly and the spring version is appropriate?

Comment: Formatter is registered correctly. However, I have found below logs :Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type java.util.ArrayList<?> to type org.springframework.core.io.Resource
 at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:313)

Comment: @Anveshan I have no converters registered in my configuration xml. certainly,there is some codes forcing framework to convert ArrayList to Resource somewhere.